# Rewind bytes::Buf while parsing tokio::net::TcpStream

Tags: rust

I'm reading a TCP stream coming from `tokio::net::TcpStream` into a `bytes::BufMut`. I then parse the buffer with `get_u8()` ([docs](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/buf/trait.Buf.html#method.get_u8)) which consumes the data from the buffer. If I realize my data is incomplete, I call `stream.read(&mut buf).await?` again.

Is there a way to not consume it and just read it conveniently or just rewind it to the beginning (e.g. opposite of `advance()`)? I want to be able to read the whole data from the beginning after the second (or more) `read` call(s).

If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Complete example:

```rust
let mut stream = tokio::net::TcpStream::connect("localhost:5432")?;
let mut buf = bytes::BufMut::with_capacity(1024);

loop {
    stream.read_buf(&mut buf).await?;

    if buf.len() < 5 {
       continue;
    }
    
    // I want to always read from the beginning of the buffer here.
    let _code = buf.get_u8();
    let len = buf.get_i32(); // Messages tell me how long they are

    if buf.len() < len as usize {
        // The whole message isn't read yet
        continue;
    }

    else {
        // We have all the data!
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to rewind. Since you're using a length-encoded message, you probably just want to use [`read_exact`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.16.1/tokio/io/trait.AsyncReadExt.html#method.read_exact) after reading the length instead of calling `read_buf` iteratively. You can also use the `read_u8`/`read_i32` methods directly from an `AsyncRead`.

```
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, BufReader};

let mut stream = BufReader::new(tokio::net::TcpStream::connect("localhost:5432").await?);

let _code = stream.read_u8().await?;
let len = stream.read_i32().await?;

let mut buf = vec![0; len as usize];
stream.read_exact(&mut buf).await?;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cdc127f70dc6a6e544fa24ed22da4e89)

Comment: Curious, do you think issuing `read_u8` and `read_i32` and `read_exact` results into 3 syscalls making this approach slower than a single `read_buf` call?

Comment: @Lev I believe yes, they would make individual syscalls. To avoid that, you can wrap the stream in a [`tokio::io::BufReader`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/struct.BufReader.html). I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to the `Read` trait from the [rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html)

> Each call to read() will attempt to pull bytes from this source into a provided buffer.

Meaning that each call to read will change the buffer by removing read bytes out of it. This is why the `read` function needs a mutable reference to `self`.

Your best bet would be to implement the behavior you want yourself in some kind of TCP wrapper. There may be a crate for this as well.

Comment: The "provided buffer" that is mutated in each call to `read` is the *other* argument (not `self`). `Read` implementers need not have an internal buffer at all (many do, of course).

Comment: If that's the case why is it `read(&mut self)` and not `read(&self)`?

Comment: The contract of `Read` is *sequentially readable*, not *concurrently readable*, which makes it possible to implement `Read` for data structures without built-in synchronization. For instance, `&[u8]` implements `Read` by advancing the data pointer. This would not be possible if `read` took `&self` because `&[u8]` isn't atomic. One way to look at this is that `Read` implementations have to mutate *some* part of `*self` so that repeated calls don't return the same thing over and over. The point I was making in my earlier comment is that it doesn't have to be an internal buffer.